# how to remove item from cart after 10 Minutes using cron job

Tags: magento2, cron, shopping-cart

i have tried to delete item from cart after 10 Minutes but it does't work 
`

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('in_cart',1 )->load();

                        foreach($productCollection as $product){
                              $quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote();
                              $item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
                              //did't get any item in $item

                        }`
```

Comment: are you able to get product collection by it $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('in_cart',1 )->load(); ?

Comment: `$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('in_cart',1 )->load();`
This code working but now get all cart item using this product